# Security risk of whitelisting google apps script ip addresses

Tags: database, security, jdbc, google-apps-script

perhaps this isn't the best place to ask this, but I wanted to be educated.

I would like to have a Google sheet interact with data on an oracle server.
I have been reading the [Google Apps Script guide for setting up JDBC connections](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc), and note that I would need to whitelist a range of IP addresses in order for this to work.

I was told by our infosec department that our db is only allowed to be accessed by onsite servers or through VPN connection, which negates using Google apps script JDBC.

My question is: what is the risk of whitelisting these IP address ranges, is spoofing a google app script IP address within the range plausible or overly cautious? What other factors am I not aware of that I should be considering?

Comment: Maybe check out the [Information Security StackExchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Thanks sandy will do

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that Apps Script needs you to [allow your database to accept connections from Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#setup_for_other_databases) in order to use JDBC with that database. There is no reasonable workaround that would not also violate the rules your infosec department has put in place.

As for whether those rules are overzealous, bare in mind that security folks need to be very cautious as a rule.  This [discussion on StackExchange may be helpful](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4533/in-what-scenarios-is-relying-on-source-ip-address-as-a-security-control-acceptab/).